# How to remove the information of the individual developer from the an Organization Apple Developer Team? Should that be a concern?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, code-signing, testflight

to whoever that can answer the questions in the post, thank you very very much in advance. The scenario is described below, the questions are in the questions section? Thank you!

### Who is in the scenario?

1. Client (A Startup that hires contract/freelance Mobile Developer to develop prototype app for funding, the startup has organization membership of Apple Developer Program)
2. Agent (A Freelance iOS Developer, who has individual of Apple Developer Program)

### What's the Client's need:

1. The Client wants to test the app that the Agent is developing.
2. The Client wants to do such test remotely without having the source code in the Client's hand.
3. For such requirements, the Client want's to use TestFlight as the solution.

### The best knowledge the Agent knew for using TestFlight as the solution for the above need:

1. The Client can invite the Agent to join Client's Apple Developer Organization Membership as a Team member from Apple Developer Offical Website.(Not refer to inviting from iTunes Connect)
2. Once the Agent accepts the invitation and joined as the member, the Agent can see Client's Develop Account appeared in the "Project/General/Team" section in Xcode, so that the Agent can archive the build, uploading to TestFlight by using Client's Team Account.
3. Thus the Client can have the app on the TestFlight so that the Client can test the app remotely without having the source code in the Client's hand, the needs of the Client is fulfilled.

### What is the Agent concern from this scenario:

1. Even if using the Client's Account for uploading the app to the TestFlight, it seems the Client's Account contains the information of Agent's Individual Developer Account, such as the Certificate of the Agent.

### Questions:

- If at some point, the Agent no longer works for the Client, is it a common approach in the software development industry that the Agent should remove the information of the Agent from the Client's Team Account? And Why?
- If the Agent should remove the information of the Agent from the Client's Team Account.

  - Can the Agent do it by him/her self without the Client's Actions?, If yes, How?
  - Or the Client must be involved? If yes, How?
- If the Agent's Developer Information never gets removed from the Client's Developer Account, what would be worst things that could happen to the Agent, and to the Client? How to prevent the worst things happens?
- What are the other things that you might think is important about this post?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rules and not about programming.

Comment: Off-topic question